# How to call & parse a seperate php file in a template using Fat-Free Framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, call, fat-free-framework

This is the index.php file in main root folder. Problem is, it does not parse the seperate phpcode.php file in the template. I tried to $f3=require(' phpcode.php'); but this will only parse the php file by itself.

```
$f3=require('3.0.7-release/lib/base.php');
$f3->route('GET /test_page',
    function($f3) {
        F3::set('_top.html','_middle.html','_bottom.html','phpcode.php','test.html');
        echo Template::instance()->render('templates/test.html');
        }
```

Comment: where is 3.0.7-release in relationship to your index.php file?

Comment: Hello? Can anyone see my response?

Comment: @Orangepill - The 3.0.7-release folder is in the same root directory as the index.php. I responded to your Q the day after you posted but for some reason my response did not post. I apologize

Comment: I'm new to stack, I wonder if people are able to see my added comments?

Comment: yeah.. we see this one...doesn't look like the first went through though

Comment: is phpcode.php in the same directory as _bottom.html?

Comment: Hey Thanks! No, _top.html, _middle.html, _bottom.html are in a folder called '_includes' and my phpcode.php is in a folder called 'templates'

Comment: try changing phpcode.php in the F3::set to '../_includes/phpcode.php'